# Beginner Graphics2D Java : repaint()

Tags: java, swing, graphics2d

I am trying to change the color of my Red Cirlces in the Action handler then `repaint()` and I couldn't figure out why it is not working.

Imports here

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import static javax.swing.JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
```

My class here:

```
public class CirclePanel extends JPanel implements ActionListener  {
    static JFrame f;
    static JButton run1, run2, reset, quit;
    static JPanel btnPanel;
    static CirclePanel circlePanel;
    static final int NUM = 5;
    static Color c;
    static Graphics2D g2;
    static Graphics2D g3; 

    public CirclePanel(){

        f = new JFrame();

        f.setTitle("Dining Philosophers");
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.setSize(1000,1000);
        f.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        btnPanel = new JPanel();
        btnPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(250, 100));
        btnPanel.add(run1 = new JButton("Run 1"));
        btnPanel.add(run2 = new JButton("Run 2"));
        btnPanel.add(reset = new JButton("Reset"));
        btnPanel.add(quit = new JButton("Quit"));

        run1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(180, 50));
        run2.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(180, 50));
        reset.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(180, 50));
        quit.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(180, 50));

        run1.addActionListener(this);


        f.add(btnPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        f.add(this, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        f.setVisible(true);
    }


    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){

        super.paintComponent(g);
        g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        g3 = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2.translate(470, 400);

        c = Color.red;

        for(int i = 0; i <  NUM; ++i){
            c = Color.red;

            g2.setColor( c);

            g2.fillOval(150, 0, 100, 100);

            g3.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            g3.fillOval(90, 0, 30, 30);

            g2.rotate(2*Math.PI/ NUM);
        }
    }
```

As you can see when I push the button Run1 it does go into the action handler and executes the repaint method, but nothing changes.

```
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if(e.getSource() == run1) {
            System.out.println("Entered Action Handler");

            g2.setColor(Color.green);

            repaint();

        }
    }
```

Here is my main:

```
    public  static void main(String[] args) {

         new CirclePanel();
    }

}
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

What's happening is:

- You are changing `g2` color in the action listener.
- Then you call `repaint();` so `paintComponent(Graphics g)` is called.
- In the `paintComponent(Graphics g)` method you are setting the `g2` color to `c` so you are overriding the changes you made in the action listener.

That's why the circles are not changing color in the end.

You should set `c = Color.RED;` in the constructor instead of in the `for` loop, then you can just change the value of `c` in the action listener `c = Color.GREEN;`.

Also you're setting `c = Color.RED;` both in the `for` loop and before it which is useless.

**EDIT:**
As suggested by `@camickr` your code is also badly structured.

- You don't need `g2` and `g3` because you can draw multiple shapes
  using the same `Graphics g` object.
- In your case you don't even need to call `g` outside of the `paintComponent` method because you can simply change the `Color c` variable as i said above.
- You also don't need all of those `static` variables. Just make them `private` and if you need to access them from outside the class you should create some `getters` and `setters`.

[Here you'll find more on static variables and some examples.](https://beginnersbook.com/2013/05/static-variable/)
[Here you'll find more about getters, setters and encapsulation.](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_encapsulation.htm)

Example of how you could change your code:

```
public class CirclePanel extends JPanel implements ActionListener  {

    private JFrame f;
    private JButton run1, run2, reset, quit;
    private JPanel btnPanel;
    private int NUM;
    private Color c;

    public CirclePanel(){

        color1 = Color.red;
        color2 = Color.black;

        NUM = 5;

        // Setup JFrame and stuff as you were doing.

    }


    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){

        super.paintComponent(g);

        g.translate(470, 400);

        for(int i = 0; i < NUM; i++){

            g.setColor(color1);
            g.fillOval(150, 0, 100, 100);

            g.setColor(color2);
            g.fillOval(90, 0, 30, 30);

            g.rotate(2*Math.PI/ NUM);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if(e.getSource() == run1) {
            System.out.println("Entered Action Handler");

            color1 = Color.green;

            repaint();
        }
    }

    // GETTERS and SETTERS if needed
}
```

Comment: Thank you, It makes perfect sense. It is working now.

Comment: (1-) @Alfiebrown, No, that is not all the changes that need to be done. Yes it may fix the problem, but the whole code is structure incorrectly. There is absolutely no need for the the g2 and g3 variables. Read the other answers and read the tutorial for the proper way to do painting.

Answer (score 2):

The Graphics objects are not long-lived, not stable, and you shouldn't be using them in this way. Instead of setting g2 or any other Graphics *field*, create a Color field, say called `Color circleColor = ...;`, and change *this*. Within the `protected void paintComponent(Graphics g)` method, call `g.setColor(circleColor);`, and this should work.

Delete these fields as they are dangerous:

```
// static Graphics2D g2;
// static Graphics2D g3;
```

Also your code shows gross over-use of the static modifier, and I would venture to recommend that none of your fields should be static except for the constant:

```
static final int NUM
```

Answer (score 1):

The repaint() method will ultimately invoke the paintComponent() method of your panel. Swing will pass in the Graphics object to be used in the painting.

In the painting code you always hardcode the Color to be RED. Don't do this.

Instead you need to define a variable in your panel class. Lets say "circleColor" (ie, "circleColor" replaces your "c" variable because variable names should be more descriptive, not just a single character).

Then in your ActionListener code you do:

```
//g2.setColor(Color.green);
circleColor = Color.green;
```

This in the paintCompnent() method you do:

```
//c = Color.red;
g.setColor(circleColor);
```

Also:

```
static Graphics2D g2;
static Graphics2D g3;
```

There is no need for any of those variable. You always use the Graphics object that is passed to the painting method.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) for more information and for better examples on how to structure your code. For example you should NOT be using static variables.